# I'm trying to run a sql file using bat file

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

But i'm getting an error like this

Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1 Server QSIH-00208, Line 1
Login failed for user 'sa'

```
@echo off
set /p param0=Enter Server :
set /p param1=Enter Database name:
set /p param2=Enter Username:
set /p param3=Enter Password:
set /p locat= Enter the location of BCP Files:

:: Creating all the SP's to convert the CQM ids to static
sqlcmd  -S %param0% -U %param2% -P %param3%  -d %param1% -i "All static id SP.SQL"
```

This is my bat file What i'm doing wrong;
My username and password are correct; But when i'm running in remote server its not working

Comment: Include the domain name along with the Server

Comment: What happens if you try and login as 'sa' using a different tool, such as "Sql Server Management Studio"?

Comment: @RB I'm able login correctly using SSMS

Comment: You will need to quote the password (or any parameters) if it contains special characters. Also, add the line @ECHO ON just before the SQLCMD line and verify that all is correct.

Comment: Yes my password is having special characters;
The thing i'm not able to understand is; its working perfectly fine in my local machine. When i try the same in a server in remote location its failing